# LLVM and Yices interfacing?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, smt

I want to call yices from a loadable module of llvm. I compiled with -lyices. Although the compilation does not report any error but at runtime the llvm module is not able to find yices symbols.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "call from a loadable module of LLVM", do you mean using `ExecutionEngine::getPointerToFunction`?

Note that this call does the equivalent of a `dlsym` on the current process, so it will only find symbols that were actually compiled into the executable. You can check (with `readelf`, for example) whether this is indeed the case. If you didn't use the library anywhere (but only try to load it in JIT), most likely the symbol has removed the references. So you have to either create dummy references or use a linker script/option to force linking all the symbols of the library, even though nothing is seen at compile time to access them.

Comment: No. By calling from llvm, I mean that calling the c_apis of yices from  runOnFunction of some Function Pass of LLvm.

Comment: @ari: you seem to have a simple linkage problem then, which has nothing to do with LLVM